Is there a set of all set-theoretical truths?
Does Tarski's undefinability theorem implies that there cannot be a set of all set-theoretical truths? Or can there be such a set (although undefinable)?

There is such a set , but this set is not recursively enumerable.

What exactly do you mean by a "set-theoretical truth"?

Alex is alluding to the fact that if you had said "arithmetic truths" instead it would be clear what you meant, namely, statements of PA true of $\mathbb{N}$ (PA cannot express this but ZF can). But to say "set-theoretic truths" you need to somehow specify a preferred model of ZF(C), in order to be able to refer to truth in that model.

@AlexKruckman Probably I had in mind two distinct questions. (1) Are there models M of ZFC in which the set of all truths in M does exist? (2) Is it coherent to think that the set of all set-theoretic truths, i.e. the set of all the sentences that are true in the set-theoretic universe V, exists?

Well, at the very least it's deeply impredicative. To decide what the set-theoretic truths are you need to determine the truth value of statements which quantify over all sets, and if the set-theoretic truths form a set this includes that set...

@Soennecken The bounty message says you're looking for a more detailed answer; is there a particular point in my answer that you'd like me to clarify?

Suppose $\mathcal{M}\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ (I think it's often better to talk about models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ rather than "the" universe $V$). All Tarski says is that we can't have $Th(\mathcal{M})$ be a definable-without-parameters element of $\mathcal{M}$. There's no problem at all with having a model $\mathcal{M}\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ with $Th(\mathcal{M})\in\mathcal{M}$; we simply won't be able to "locate" $Th(\mathcal{M})$ inside $\mathcal{M}$.
The following may demystify things. Let $\mathcal{M}\models\mathsf{ZFC}$, and for simplicity let's assume that $\mathcal{M}$ is transitive (this isn't a huge issue). For each ordinal $\alpha\in \mathcal{M}$ let $r_\alpha=Th(V_\alpha^\mathcal{M})$ be the theory of the thing $\mathcal{M}$ thinks is the $\alpha$th level of the cumulative hierarchy. Each $r_\alpha$ is in $\mathcal{M}$; moreover, for each $\alpha>\omega+1$, we have $r_\alpha\in V_\alpha^\mathcal{M}$. However, we won't have $r_\alpha$ be parameter-freely-definable in $V_\alpha^\mathcal{M}$. We will often have $r_\alpha$ be parameter-freely-definable in $V_\beta^\mathcal{M}$ for some larger $\beta$ ... but $r_\beta\not=r_\alpha$ in such cases.
So there's nothing dangerous about a structure containing its own theory somewhere, it just has to be "hard to find" in a sense.
